# KeyError: "None of [Index(['Zomba', 'Lilongwe', 'Blantyre', 'Mzuzu'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]", I am using Python Panda

Tags: python, pandas

The following is my dataset and libraries involved:

```
             import pandas as pd
             import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
             %matplotlib inline

             data={
             'city':['Zomba','Lilongwe','Blantyre','Mzuzu'],
             'rank':[1,4,3,8],
            'region':['south','central','south','north']
            }`

            frame=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['city','rank','region'])

            myplot=frame.plot(frame['city'], kind='bar', legend=True)
```

After running the above snippet, I am getting this key error:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Zomba', 'Lilongwe', 'Blantyre', 'Mzuzu'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

I tried getting my column data with this code:
frame.get('city', default=0) and I also tried getting it using frame.iloc[:,0].

and the data is available as shown below:
0       Zomba
1    Lilongwe
2    Blantyre
3       Mzuzu
Name: city, dtype: object

But when I try to plot, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Take out the frame[]
`myplot=frame.plot('city', kind='bar', legend=True)`

Comment: @Michael Harawa, `myplot=frame.set_index('city').plot(kind='bar', legend=True)` ?

Comment: You need to remove the columns parameter from 
`frame=pd.DataFrame(data)`, they are already imputed from the dict keys

Comment: @RodiX this has been noted, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines should look like below, you already apply the function plot on your frame, don't need to assign again the series, just the column name.

```
frame=pd.DataFrame(data)

myplot=frame.plot('city', kind='bar', legend=True)
```